# Hash::extract with HABTM

Tags: cakephp

I'm having difficulty understanding the syntax of Hash::extract when dealing with HABTM.

I have data coming back from a find() that looks like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'EventsGroup' => array(
            'id' => '34',
            'event_id' => '5',
            'group_id' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'EventsGroup' => array(
            'id' => '29',
            'event_id' => '2',
            'group_id' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

I'm trying to get to an array that looks like: `array(x,y,z)` where x,y,z are `event_id`'s.

The Cake documentation's example looks like:

```
$users = $this->User->find("all");
$results = Hash::extract($users, '{n}.User.id');
```

Based on that, I tried:

```
$eventsGroups = $this->EventsGroup->findAllByGroupId($groupid);
$secEvents = Hash::extract($eventsGroups, '{n}.{EventsGroup}.event_id' );
$secEvents2 = Hash::extract($eventsGroups, '{n}.EventsGroup.event_id' );
$secEvents3 = Hash::extract($eventsGroups, '{n}.[text=EventsGroup].event_id);
```

None of which worked.

I found a way to get what I wanted without using Hash::extract, but I'd like to use it as some of the other methods will be useful to me down the road.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 $eventsGroups = $this->EventsGroup->findAllByGroupId($groupid);
 $secEvents = Hash::extract($eventsGroups, '{n}.EventsGroup[event_id]' );
```

As the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#hash-path-syntax) says to retrieve a field you should use a matcher and not a expression. And the brackets ({}) are not needed, they are used to build expressions like '{n}.{s}'...